# Android create a Bluetooth SPP connection with custom passkey

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I want to create a Bluetooth SPP connection with a embedded device.
I want to use the secured mode so I use the following function

createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid)

This will generate a passkey and try to pair with the device.
I do not want the Bluetooth to generate the passkey, I want to give custom passkey. ex: 0000/1234

Comment: use that createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid)

Comment: Your correct if I want to connect without any passkey, but I want to give a custom passkey.